# Show All Results From One Table Not Listed In The Other (Junction) Table By :id

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I have 2 tables I'm interacting with.

The first table: acl_permissions (is just a normal table).

```
+-----------------------------------+
|           acl_permissions         |
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id |     name    |   permission   |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | Add User    | addUser        |
|  2 | Edit User   | editUser       |
|  3 | Delete User | deleteUser     |
|  4 | View User   | viewUser       |
|  5 | Test Name   | testPermission |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

The second table: acl_group_permissions is a junction table.

```
+--------------------------------+
|      acl_group_permissions     |
+----+----------+----------------+
| id | group_id | permissions_id |
+----+----------+----------------+
|  1 |     1    |        1       |
|  2 |     1    |        2       |
|  3 |     1    |        3       |
|  4 |     1    |        4       |
|  5 |     2    |        4       |
|  6 |     2    |        5       |
+----+----------+----------------+
```

I have a query to show all the permissions that are currently allowed by group_id '1'.

```
SELECT acl_permissions.id, acl_permissions.name, acl_permissions.permission
FROM acl_permissions
JOIN acl_group_permissions
ON acl_permissions.id = acl_group_permissions.permission_id
WHERE acl_group_permissions.group_id = 1
```

The result is:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id |     name    |   permission   |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | Add User    | addUser        |
|  2 | Edit User   | editUser       |
|  3 | Delete User | deleteUser     |
|  4 | View User   | viewUser       |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

**MY PROBLEM**

I want a query to show all the permissions that are not allowed by the group_id '1'.

The desired result would be:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id |     name    |   permission   |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  5 | Test Name   | testPermission |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

The closest I have to it is:

```
SELECT acl_permissions.id, acl_permissions.name, acl_permissions.permission
FROM acl_permissions
LEFT OUTER JOIN acl_group_permissions
ON acl_permissions.id = acl_group_permissions.permission_id
WHERE acl_group_permissions.group_id IS NULL
```

With the result being:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id |     name    |   permission   |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  4 | View User   | viewUser       |
|  5 | Test Name   | testPermission |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

How do I feed the group_id of '1' into the query to eliminate the id 4.

I have Googled plenty but I'm find examples and solutions that are close but to exact to my situation.

IE: Using a junction table. My MySQL Join Types infographics are of no help either.

Help..! My brain is melting..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use a join logic, use instead a simpler one :

Select all permissions_id that group_1 has (from acl_group_permissions), then select all acl_permissions id that are not in the ones selected. Translated to SQL, it becomes:

```
SELECT acl_permissions.id, acl_permissions.name, acl_permissions.permission
FROM acl_permissions
WHERE acl_permissions.id NOT 
IN (
    SELECT permissions_id
    FROM acl_group_permissions
    WHERE group_id = 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Understandable, logical and in hindsight obvious. Now I know all about NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but this would work

```
SELECT acl_permissions.id, acl_permissions.name, acl_permissions.permission
FROM acl_permissions
JOIN acl_group_permissions
ON acl_permissions.id = acl_group_permissions.permission_id
WHERE acl_group_permissions.group_id != 1 and acl_permissions.id 
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT acl_permissions.id
FROM acl_permissions
JOIN acl_group_permissions
ON acl_permissions.id = acl_group_permissions.permission_id
WHERE acl_group_permissions.group_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT A.*
FROM acl_permissions A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM acl_group_permissions WHERE group_id=1) B
ON A.id = B.permissions_id WHERE B.id IS NULL;
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS matt;
CREATE DATABASE matt;
USE matt
CREATE TABLE acl_permissions
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(32),
    permission varchar(32),
    primary key (id)
);
CREATE TABLE acl_group_permissions
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    group_id int not null,
    permissions_id int not null,
    primary key (id)
);
INSERT INTO acl_permissions
(name,permission) VALUES
('Add User'   ,'addUser'),
('Edit User'  ,'editUser'),
('Delete User','deleteUser'),
('View User'  ,'viewUser'),
('Test Name'  ,'testPermission');
INSERT INTO acl_group_permissions
(group_id,permissions_id) VALUES
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,5);
SELECT * FROM acl_permissions;
SELECT * FROM acl_group_permissions;
```

## YOUR SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS matt;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.39 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE matt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE matt
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE acl_permissions
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     name varchar(32),
    ->     permission varchar(32),
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE acl_group_permissions
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     group_id int not null,
    ->     permissions_id int not null,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO acl_permissions
    -> (name,permission) VALUES
    -> ('Add User'   ,'addUser'),
    -> ('Edit User'  ,'editUser'),
    -> ('Delete User','deleteUser'),
    -> ('View User'  ,'viewUser'),
    -> ('Test Name'  ,'testPermission');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO acl_group_permissions
    -> (group_id,permissions_id) VALUES
    -> (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,5);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM acl_permissions;
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id | name        | permission     |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | Add User    | addUser        |
|  2 | Edit User   | editUser       |
|  3 | Delete User | deleteUser     |
|  4 | View User   | viewUser       |
|  5 | Test Name   | testPermission |
+----+-------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM acl_group_permissions;
+----+----------+----------------+
| id | group_id | permissions_id |
+----+----------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 |              1 |
|  2 |        1 |              2 |
|  3 |        1 |              3 |
|  4 |        1 |              4 |
|  5 |        2 |              4 |
|  6 |        2 |              5 |
+----+----------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT A.*
    -> FROM acl_permissions A LEFT JOIN
    -> (SELECT * FROM acl_group_permissions WHERE group_id=1) B
    -> ON A.id = B.permissions_id WHERE B.id IS NULL;
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | name      | permission     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  5 | Test Name | testPermission |
+----+-----------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Wow..! I love your systematic approach in answering my question and your answer does work..! The only reason I did not accept this as the  answer is because of it's complexity compared to the other. I have never seen a query written like this. I do have a lot more to learn. +1 for your logic and presentation.